# Qwt Analog Widget

Tags: c++, qt

Я скачал [qwt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/files/qwt/). Мне нужны там только виджеты. Могу я их закинуть в папку :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и использовать в своём приложении? И как их использовать, если это возможно?

Comment: ИМХО проще статику собрать (можно даже подпроектом) и не мучаться с зависимостями... кроме того тут с лицензией вопросы возникают: QWT прямо разрешает статическую линковку, а вот такое потрошение уже, пожалуй, будет считаться производной работой и потребует лицензирования приложения под [L]GPL2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Технически без проблем, но например, для добавления `QwtAnalogClock` требуется добавить в проект 41 файл:

qwt_abstract_scale.cpp
qwt_abstract_scale.h
qwt_abstract_scale_draw.cpp
qwt_abstract_scale_draw.h
qwt_abstract_slider.cpp
qwt_abstract_slider.h
qwt_analog_clock.cpp
qwt_analog_clock.h
qwt_clipper.cpp
qwt_clipper.h
qwt_color_map.cpp
qwt_color_map.h
qwt_dial.cpp
qwt_dial.h
qwt_dial_needle.cpp
qwt_dial_needle.h
qwt_global.h
qwt_interval.cpp
qwt_interval.h
qwt_math.cpp
qwt_math.h
qwt_painter.cpp
qwt_painter.h
qwt_point_polar.cpp
qwt_point_polar.h
qwt_round_scale_draw.cpp
qwt_round_scale_draw.h
qwt_scale_div.cpp
qwt_scale_div.h
qwt_scale_draw.cpp
qwt_scale_draw.h
qwt_scale_engine.cpp
qwt_scale_engine.h
qwt_scale_map.cpp
qwt_scale_map.h
qwt_text.cpp
qwt_text.h
qwt_text_engine.cpp
qwt_text_engine.h
qwt_transform.cpp
qwt_transform.h

ну а дальше как с обычными компонентами

mainwindow.h

```
class QwtAnalogClock;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
...
    QwtAnalogClock *clock;
...
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "qwt/qwt_analog_clock.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ...
    clock = new QwtAnalogClock();
    lt->addWidget(clock);
}
```

Comment: А есть подобные модули, где только виджеты ?

Comment: Здесь тоже только виджеты